# webpack preprocessor in karma config doesn't process required html files in my tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, webpack, karma-runner

I have a `webpack.config.js` loaders to handle `.html` modules required in my `entry.js` file.

```
{
  test: /.html$/,
  exclude:/init-templates(\\|\/)index.html$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options:{
        name:'[hash].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'assets/ajax/'
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'extract-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'html-loader',
      options: {
        attrs: ['img:src', 'link:href'],
        minimize: prod,
        removeComments: prod,
        collapseWhitespace: prod,
        minifyJS: prod,
        minifyCSS: prod,
        interpolate:'require'
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

and it works great when I just run `> webpack` in the cmd. It moves all neccessary (required) `.html` files to the `prod/assets/ajax/` dir as I expect.
When I remove these loaders, of course `Module parse failed:'some/path/tempate.html'. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` error occurs.

Now, I want to run my `tests.js` file in karma. I use in my `karma.conf.js`:

```
files: [
  {pattern: 'dist/components/main/tests.js', watched:true}
]
preprocessors: {
  'dist/components/main/tests.js': ['webpack']
},
```

And webpack processes my `tests.js` file well as long as I do not require `.html` file there. When I require `.html` file it returs `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` - as if html loaders would not exist in my `webpack.config.js`.

Why karma/webpack do not see my html loaders in my `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Ok I found what is wrong, I've just added `webpack: require('./webpack.config')` to my `karma.conf.js` file..